# cannot access value on pageload event on ther server-side

Tags: asp.net, pageload, hidden-field

I want to use hiddenField to get monitor's width and length value.

But it works only after I clicked on the button, i can access hfClientScreenHeight.Value and hfclientScreenWidth.Value. Otherwise, I get null.

input value seems fine on the server side.How can I fix this problem? Thanks!

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="cph_Head" Runat="Server">
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function GetResolution() {
        document.getElementById("clientScreenWidth").value = screen.width;
        document.getElementById("clientScreenHeight").value = screen.height;
        document.getElementById("cph_Body_hfClientScreenHeight").value = screen.height;
        document.getElementById("cph_Body_hfClientScreenWidth").value = screen.weight;
    }
</script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="cph_Body" Runat="Server">
    <body onload="GetResolution();">
    <asp:HiddenField ID="hfClientScreenHeight" runat="server" />
    <asp:HiddenField ID="hfclientScreenWidth" runat="server" />
    <asp:Button ID="test" Width="50" runat="server"/>
    <input type="text"  name="clientScreenHeight" id="clientScreenHeight" />
    <input type="text"  name="clientScreenWidth" id="clientScreenWidth" />
</asp:Content>
```

aspx.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var hh = hfClientScreenHeight.Value;
    var ww = hfclientScreenWidth.Value;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how it should be. The codebehind can't access them because it just served them to the client. You have to send the data back to the page through postback in order for the page to actually get it. You have to send this data back to the server. There are numerous topics on this. You can try through an ajax call, but that doesn't get you anything for the page though because you have to use a web service which is a static call. You can use an updatepanel as well.

I found an article at: http://techbrij.com/browser-height-width-server-responsive-design-asp-net  which may have an interesting solution.

Don't rely on this though. It's much better to use a responsive design framework to assist in handling the different viewport sizes on the browser. Getting the width and height takes more work than it's worth especially trying to do it across all devices, and a responsive framework gives you so many more options. Got a large screen then a particular portion of the page can be shown and another hidden. Same goes for tiny screen, show content in a way that benefits the screen and hide the version for larger viewports.

Tip: Don't hard-code the client id's of a server control in a script. It makes it brittle because as soon as you move that control the client id changes (or if you put the page in a masterpage, etc..). Instead, simply use a response.write shorthand to get the unique client id like so:

```
document.getElementById("<%= hfClientScreenWidth.ClientID %>").value = screen.weight;
```

Comment: I would like to set width, height dynamically. Once a user open a web page, JavaScript would be executed. ASP.net can assign a new width, height value on page_load event.

Comment: You can't do that. You have to post back because ASP.Net can't get the value unless you do.